# Make Node.js support the shebang (#!) for JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, shebang

Some scripting languages (such as Python or Bash) use `#` for comments.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print 'hello, world'
```

I can run the script:

```
python script.py
```

Or

```
./script.py
```

Is it possible to make JavaScript support shebang?

Comment: See also what is [the appropriate shebang for Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638520/appropriate-hashbang-for-node-js-scripts/28646724).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Yes, you can simply use `#!/usr/bin/env node` (or whatever the name of your JavaScript interpreter is, it works fine with `js` (spidermonkey), too).

```
[me@hades:~]> cat > test.js
#!/usr/bin/env node
console.log('hi');
[me@hades:~]> chmod +x test.js
[me@hades:~]> ./test.js
hi
```

Most likely both interpreters test if the first line begins with `#!` and in this case it is skipped.

Comment: Does node ignore the first line? `#` is not a comment in javascript.

Comment: Yes, if it's a shebang line. Otherwise it would be a SyntaxError.

Comment: YUI Compressor throws an error saying that this (the #!) is an illegal character. Further, my IDE (Eclipse) shows this as an error as well. What gives? Is it valid or not?