# Making node.js code to a executable file in MacOS

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

I have a nodejs app `app.js` which I'm able to execute with help of the command line tool (changing to the direction of the app and executing the command 
`node app.js`
before that the application is installed with `npm install`). To make it easier in the daily use i would like to make the app executable, both parts, the installation as well as the trigger of the app.

The app is for generating a small report, I already tried it with a script where I saved the command `node app.js`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28646724/2312051 - this might be helpful

Answer (score 1):

You might use [pkg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg).

> This command line interface enables you to package your Node.js project into an executable that can be run even on devices without Node.js installed.

Comment: hi,
I was able to package the app but the packaged app is not running on Windows (as .exe file). Will try the packaged MacOS app on Monday, this is way more important than the windows part.