# node and shebang : help executing via command line

Tags: node.js, path, shebang

My node installation is at:

`/usr/local/bin/node`

and I've added the shebang:

`#!/usr/local/bin/node`

to the top of the file and given my node app file the permissions 755, but when I try to run:

`> ./my-app`

I get the old:

`-bash: ./my-app: No such file or directory`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: my guess would be you're simply in a wrong directory.  `ls -l ./my-app` should help.

Comment: Whoops, actually, I guess it was because I had .js at the end of my file: removing the file type, from "my-app.js" to "my-app" allowed me to run it with `> ./my-app`

Answer (score 207):

The node shebang is:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

Not all systems place node in the same location, its possible that you have the location incorrectly. This will find them all.

[Source](http://dailyjs.com/2012/03/01/unix-node-arguments/)

[Also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696222/how-to-make-javascript-support-shebang)

Comment: @asking you should be able to have the `.js` part on there

Comment: Hmm, then my head-scratching continues: My file was named "my-app.js", have the shebang `#!/usr/bin/env node` and node is on my path at "/usr/local/bin/node". As soon as I removed the ".js", the Mac OS considered it a binary, I suppose, and I was able to execute it as such. But now I'm confused again - par for the course.

Comment: @secretformula for the record, it works on my macOS (Sierra) without extension, like it should. `chmod +x` was of course necessary.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638520/appropriate-hashbang-for-node-js-scripts/28646724) explains in detail why this is the correct shebang.