# Does the hashbang (#!) have any functionality client side?

Tags: javascript, shebang, hashbang

I recently learned about the [hashbang](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#comments) syntax for writing comments in JavaScript, and need to know if it is or has the potential to be any different then just putting a `//` at the top of a file. Are there any conventions associated with the hashbang?

**I am referring to usage in a browser environment only**, not in a shell or NodeJS, etc.

I am asking because I am writing about JavaScript syntax and need to make sure it is 100% correct.

Comment: Wow, I am incorrect, shebangs are valid JavaScript. Will have to see where in ECMAScript sometime soon. As for your question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696222/make-node-js-support-the-shebang-for-javascript-files) is a post about it.

Comment: [What exactly does "/usr/bin/env node" do at the beginning of node files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33509816) probably a better dupe target

Comment: @SuperStormer I am referring to JS in the browser, rather than NodeJS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hashbang has no meaning to JavaScript, as far as it's concerned it's just a comment. The only reason it exists is because Unix treats files beginning with `#!` specially when you try to run them as commands, and this can be used to run `node.js` automatically on a server.

This is meaningless in a browser, which loads scripts explicitly. So The hashbang has no special function on the client.

Answer (score 0):

No, `#!` doesn't have any JavaScript functionality, neither on the server nor on the client side. It's just a comment that does nothing. It has a functionality in executable files on some operating systems, but that has nothing to do with JavaScript - it's just to allow writing JavaScrit scripts as text files that make use of this operating system functionality.

On a related note, JavaScript does also use [`<!-- …` and `-->` as comment syntax](https://262.ecma-international.org/13.0/#sec-html-like-comments), which is equally useless in non-HTML context like in serverside javascript, but it's permitted for compatibility anyway.